# The association refers to the inverse side field which does not exist. | Symfony2 / Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

So, there are a couple of similar issues around SO but they didn't help me in the end..
I've checked my code over and over again, but I can't figure out the error.

When getting all Comakers in a category (OneToMany) I get NULL instead of the desired array.

In my **Comaker** entity I have:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="comakers")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryid", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $category;
```

Next in my **Category** class:

```
/*
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comaker", mappedBy="category"
*/
private $comakers;
```

The error I get when checking my mapping:

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Zoho\Bundle\Entity\Comaker' mapping is invalid:
* The association Zoho\Bundle\Entity\Comaker#category refers to the inverse side field Zoho\Bundle\Entity\Category#comakers which does not exist.
```

If you ask me, Category#comakers **does exist**!
On top of that, when generating entities, doctrine is nog generating anything for Category#comakers either. Cache has been cleared, even removed all getters and setters and Entity.php~ files for clean generation, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: You missed to close the parenthesis for `private $comakers;` so you need to have `* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comaker", mappedBy="category")`

Comment: Very valid comment! Just added it, but apparently it was not the problem :(

Comment: Good; You answered your own question by changing `/*` to `/**`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you missed to close the parenthesis for `private $comakers;`
Next you need to change `/*` to `/**`

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comaker", mappedBy="category")
*/
private $comakers;
```

Comment: Deleted my answer to give you the wel deserved credit ;-)

Comment: awesome, how a simple * can be a pain in the ass...

Comment: Excellent Buddy !!